# How to use Protractor to find a empty cell in a table

Tags: javascript, html, testing, html-table, protractor

If the field is a non-empty cell, I can use filter or by.cssContainingText to find the td. But what if the the td is empty?

For example, the following table has two exactly same row. each row has 5 p-editable-column. But all columns are empty, so how can I select a specific column? e.g I want to select the second p-editable-column on the first row.

```
<tbody class="p-datatable-tbody">
    <tr class="p-datatable-row blackFont" draggable="false" style="height: 28px;">
        <td class="" style="min-width: 2.6em; width: 2.6em; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;"></td>
        <td class="" style="min-width: 2.8em; width: 2.8em; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;"><i aria-hidden="true"
                class="file outline vertically flipped icon link noteButton"></i></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="p-datatable-row blackFont" draggable="false" style="height: 28px;">
        <td class="" style="min-width: 2.6em; width: 2.6em; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;"></td>
        <td class="" style="min-width: 2.8em; width: 2.8em; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;"><i aria-hidden="true"
                class="file outline vertically flipped icon link noteButton"></i></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
        <td class="p-editable-column" style="width: 5em; white-space: pre-line;"><a tabindex="0"
                class="p-cell-editor-key-helper p-hidden-accessible"><span></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it locating them by css and indicating the index. For example, if you want the second `p-editable-column` column, you'd first have to locate the first row:

`const firstRow = element.all(by.css('.p-datatable-row.blackFont')).get(0);`

Then locate the 2nd column within that row:

`const secondCol = firstRow.all(by.css('.p-editable-column')).get(1);`